# udev attribute cannot be set on boot

Tags: centos6, udev, sr-iov

I'm setting up SR-IOV for my Intel I350 igb on CentOS 6.6 (2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64, udev 147) using udev. I have modified a rule I used in CentOS 7 (3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64, udev 208). When I do "udevadm test" on CentOS 6.6, the rule is matched correctly and sets the sriov_numvfs attribute to the desired number and enables SR-IOV accordingly:

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/igbsriov.rules
KERNEL=="0000:01:00.0", SUBSYSTEM=="pci", DRIVER=="igb", ATTR{vendor}=="0x8086", ATTR{device}=="0x1521", WAIT_FOR="/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/sriov_numvfs", ATTR{sriov_numvfs}="7"
```

However, when the computer is reboot, sriov_numvfs attribute is not set until I perform udevadm trigger

What I might be missing? Ideas?